# How to set time expiry to windows application in c#?

Tags: c#, windows

I am a novice software developer and I am building desktop applications using C#. I want to make my applications expire and generate a license file to activate the application after it expires. Meaning I want to include a time bomb to all my applications and detonate it by using the generated license file.

Comment: write your program to check the date and the licence key on the loading

Comment: This is too broad. Try to concentrate on a single specific issue that you face.

Comment: ok my specific issue is i am taking system time k.when day period over for ex 5 days it will not expire if i change the system date

Comment: In addition to being too broad, this mechanism of "timing out" and forcing users to buy a license is also considered equivalent to coercion and is illegal in certain countries / jurisdictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing a windows 8 app and you want to find out a way to create a trial version of your app then I think the following article does a pretty good job of explaining how to do it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694065.aspx

Comment: i didnt get anything?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this - the .NET-Way is described here in this MSDN-Article:

[How to: License Components and Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe8b1eh9.aspx)